# Where can I find examples of really bad writing?

Tags: writing-style, errors

Do you know where I can find examples of really bad writing?

I'm looking for garbled sentence structure, errors in spelling, grammar, and vocabulary, redundancy, tautology, internal contradictions, go-nowhere phrases, truncation, abuse of idioms, anything like that.

Ideally it would be scientific or technical writing, but anything factual rather than poetic would be helpful. It needs to actually have some meaningful content, albeit badly presented. Thanks.

Clarification: I'm looking for paragraph-long examples, not fragments. [Here is an illustrative example.](http://pastebin.com/GKkhjdcY)

Comment: Have you heard of YouTube?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/foreign-signs.html

Comment: I'm looking for extended pieces of writing -- failed attempts to communicate something substantial.

Comment: Go onto any Cambridge exam site and look at sample answers to questions. The poor ones make very good studies in poor grammar, choice of expression and general ability to fulfill their intended purpose

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources. And since it requests paragraph-long examples containing many mistakes rather than examples of individual mistakes (which I agree could be useful teaching materials), this request seems more judgmental than instructional in intent.

Comment: @spraff Extended pieces of writing, no matter how bad, tend to be copyrighted...

Comment: @anemone - I suspect it would be difficult to plausibly assert copyright protection in the case of press releases, because those are designed to be disseminated and reproduced in the media.

Comment: @ErikKowal I said 'tend to be'. What I meant was that a majority would be. What I meant by majority ... was perhaps in terms of length. A rule of thumb that must have lurked behind this reasoning is that the longer the text, the more likely it is to be copyrighted. With a few glorious exceptions, of course.

Comment: Welcome to the Internet. Many questions pre-edit in Stack Exchange are prime examples of the type requested.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has some great examples.

Look on [Wikipedia:Template messages/Cleanup#Style of writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Template_messages/Cleanup#Style_of_writing) for links to lists of articles that have been marked as (in various ways) lacking.

E.g.

- [In need of copy edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:WhatLinksHere/Template:copy_edit&limit=500)
- [In need of cleanup / rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:WhatLinksHere/Template:cleanup-rewrite&limit=500)